# How to search in pl/sql local collections?

Tags: collections, plsql

How can i make query to PL/SQL local collections like `TABLE OF` and `VARRAY`?
I searched the web , but whatever I found is to iterate over them eg. `FOR LOOP`!
Is there any facility to make query to them?

Thanks.

Comment: could this: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/return_table.html be the info you are looking for?

Comment: thanks Najzero,but you know, by declaring types (like local collections) with "CREATE OR REPLACE" keywords , they'll become global types that SQL can SELECT withing them. but in my situation i don't have global registered types  . (unless when i should do that!)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL engine can make queries, the PL/SQL engine cannot. So you need to cast your collections to table types that are known to the SQL engine.

SQL doesn't know about types declared in packages, so you have to declare them at the global level.

Judging by your comment it seems like you pretty much figured it out already.

Comment: thanks Klas. But rather than SELECT, is there any facility or fast way (instead of FOR LOOP) to find a record within a local collection?